# In Angular how do I test that my scope.myfunction() is being called from a scope watcher from within my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In Angular how do I test that my scope.myfunction() is being called from a scope watcher from within my controller?

**My controller code:**

```
    $scope.$watch("location", () => {
        $scope.myFunction();
    });
```

**This is my test:**

```
  it("should call the map resize function on tab change", function () {
      scope.location= "test";
      scope.$digest();

      expect(scope.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Do you have a spyOn(scope, "myFunction") somewhere in there? That should be the only thing missing.

Comment: thanks Eric, could you also help me with this unit test: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476629/in-angular-version1-how-do-i-test-that-my-scope-myfunction-is-being-called-fro